# Problems with boost::ptr_vector and boost::any

Tags: c++, boost, stl, auto-ptr, ptr-vector

ok, so I got a doubt, I want to know if this is possible:

I'm using a database, with generic data (strings, ints, bools, etc...). Whenever an object is constructed or a member of an object is modified, I have to query the database with the specific action (SELECT or UPDATE).
First of all, this isn't a DB related question, my real problem is that I have a ptr_vector which holds boost::any's pointers to members of the object. In code something like this:

```
class Enemy{
  private:
    //some private data...
  public:
    auto_ptr<int> ID_Enemy;
    auto_ptr<string> Enemy_Name;
    //miscellaneous methods...
};
```

then I pass the members I want to modify to a function of another miscellaneous class which takes as argument a boost::any*:

```
misc_class.addValues((boost::any*)(ID_Enemy.get()));
misc_class.addValues((boost::any*)(Enemy_Name.get()));
```

that same class accepts the any*, and does the following:

```
auto_ptr<boost::any> val2(val); //being val, the passed any*
Enemy_Values.push_back(val2);
```

Enemy_Values is a ptr_vector. So when I access this misc_class which has Enemy_Values as member, I want to change the value to which an auto_ptr inside is pointing:

```
misc_class.Enemy_Values[0] = (boost::any)(69);
```

And here, I get a violation error. I've tried many things, and someone told me that I shouldn't be using containers of auto_ptr or converting back and forth with boost::any. Is this that I am doing possible, or there is a better and more intuitive way?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

`(boost::any*)(ID_Enemy.get())` performs a `reinterpret_cast` since you are casting unrelated pointer types. This means you get an invalid pointer to an `any`, pointing to what is really an integer.
Instead, construct a temporary boost::any object and pass it by reference to addValues:

```
misc_class.addValues(boost::any(ID_Enemy.get());
```

Your use of `auto_ptr` is in fact incorrect: `auto_ptr` deletes objects on the freestore but here we're dealing with locals instead. `addValues` merely needs to push the *value* of the `any` object into the vector:

```
Enemy_Values.push_back(val);
```

... and Enemy_Values should just be a std::vector.

You *could* do this with a ptr_vector and freestore-allocated `boost::any` objects, but that would be more complicated than necessary.

Answer (score 0):

auto_ptr has a [number of problems](http://aszt.inf.elte.hu/~gsd/halado_cpp/ch05s03.html).  Since you are already using boost, why not use boost::shared_ptr instead?